# Closed Range Theorem in Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

In our functional analysis class we stated the closed range theorem for Hilbert spaces and the proof was left as an exercise for the interested reader.

I am however having trouble proving the implication
\begin{equation}T \text{open} \Rightarrow T^* \text{open},
\end{equation}
where $T^*$ denotes the (Hilberst space) adjoint of $T$ and $T$ is a densly defined, closed linear operator.

We defined the term ‚open‘ a bit different, than I think it is usually done. Our professor called a linear operator $T$ open if the image $T(U)$ of every open set $U$ is open in $R(T)$ w.r.t. the subspace topology $R(T)$ inherits from the target space.

I would be glad for any suggestions and thanks in advance.